# Include build directory in nuget package using visual studio pack

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I'm attempting to create a nupkg with Visual Studio using the built in nuget package building and include the build directory from my project in the nupkg. It seems like it should be a fairly simple task but I can't get it to work. From my googling adding either of these to my csproj file should work, but both create an empty 'build' directory in the nupkg:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="build\**">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>build\</PackagePath>
      <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Using `nuget pack` to create the package with the following in my nuspec does work:

```
  <files>
        <!-- Include everything in \build -->
    <file src="build\**" target="build" />
  </files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to [upgrade the project to SDK type](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) (Xamarin binding projects by default use the old format but seem to work with the new type) and then use:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="build\**">
        <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

To include the build directory. The alternative is using `nuget pack`.

When converting the project make sure to leave in the Xamarin import:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.ObjCBinding.CSharp.targets" />
```

Here's how my project file looks afterwards:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId></PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>3.3.2</PackageVersion>
    <ReleaseVersion>$(PackageVersion)</ReleaseVersion>
    <AssemblyVersion>$(PackageVersion)</AssemblyVersion>
    <Authors>Nick Brook</Authors>
    <Description></Description>
    <Copyright></Copyright>
    <PackageProjectUrl></PackageProjectUrl>
    <Summary></Summary>
    <PackageTags></PackageTags>
    <Title></Title>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Initial Release</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <PackageOutputPath>packed</PackageOutputPath>
    <PackOnBuild>true</PackOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ObjcBindingApiDefinition Include="ApiDefinition.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ObjcBindingCoreSource Include="Structs.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Structs.cs" Condition=" '$(EnableDefaultCompileItems)' == 'true' " />
    <Compile Remove="ApiDefinition.cs" Condition=" '$(EnableDefaultCompileItems)' == 'true' " />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="packed\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Build.Download" Version="0.4.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Build.Packaging" Version="0.2.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="build\**">
      <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.ObjCBinding.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 9):

> Include build directory in nuget package using visual studio pack

According to the document [Including content in a package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package), you should use the properties `<Pack>true</Pack>` and `<PackagePath>build\</PackagePath>`:

> If you want to copy all your content to only a specific root folder(s) (instead of content and contentFiles both), you can use the MSBuild property ContentTargetFolders, which defaults to "content;contentFiles" but can be set to any other folder names.
>
> `PackagePath` can be a semicolon-delimited set of target paths.
>   Specifying an empty package path would add the file to the root of the
>   package.

So, you can change your ItemGroup like following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="build\**" Pack="True" PackagePath="build\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Update:**

> I believe this is the same as what I added but in a different XML
>   structure and without the Pack attribute

The `Pack` attribute is the key point. It works fine with your XML structure and the Pack attribute. You should make sure you have the files in the **build** folder in **your project folder**:

[image]

Check my test demo below:

[image]

**Update2:**

Ah! You are using the `.net framework` project!! That the reason for this issue. This method is used for `.net standard` and `.net core` project by default and it not work for `.net framework`. To resolve this issue you have to use the `.nupsec` file, like you post in the question.

If you still want to include build directory in nuget package **using visual studio pack**, you need change your project type to **SDK** type:

Check [this document](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) for some more details.

Then you can use the method, which we talked about before.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe this is the same as what I added but in a different XML structure and without the Pack attribute which I also tried (so have now added to the question). Regardless, both have the same result – an empty build directory in the nupkg.

Comment: @Nick, Check my Update answer. If there is anything different from you,  please point it out for free, I will keep follow.

Comment: I copied your xml but it still created an empty build folder. I’m using visual studio for Mac, will try windows later but I don’t think it is working either. The files are in the build directory. The nuspec file include does work.

Comment: @Nick, As you can see, it works fine on my side. But I don't currently have a VS for MAC environment, so I could not verify this for you, you can test it on the windows, and if it not work, please share a simple sample project via onedirve, I will check it.

Comment: @Nick, You are using the .net framework project!! That the reason for this issue. Check my Update2  answer for details. Hope this helps.

Comment: How confusing! Everything else works except including files... Will converting to SDK type be possible for this iOS framework binding project?

Comment: @Nick, you can check it, I don't currently have a VS for MAC environment, so I can not give you an accurate answer, when I free, I will check it.

Comment: I converted the project and it still doesn't work, but what does work is:
`<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="build\**">
      <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: I have resolved it using the above yes. But it would seem like a bug that your solution doesn't work and that it doesn't work in the old project format (since it can create packages and even the build directory, just not copy the files)

Comment: @Nick, It works fine on windows, I am not sure if it is a bug for VS for MAC. You can report it to nuget team. And since you have resolve this issue, could you please share your solution here? It helps others read this thread. Thanks.